# Typed Racket extend gui classes

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I want to extend the class  `horizontal-panel%`but somehow I am getting this error message:

```
class has init `stretchable-height' that is not in expected type in: (class horizontal-panel% (super-new))
```

This is my code so far:

```
#lang typed/racket
(require typed/racket/gui)

(define-type Graph-Tab%
  (Class #:implements  Horizontal-Panel%

         ))
(: graph-tab% : Graph-Tab%)
(define graph-tab%
  (class horizontal-panel%
    (super-new)

    ))
```

As you can probably tell I am very new to racket and I am still learning.

Comment: did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what that error message means is that you need to "init" all of the things from that class.

One useful way to do this is to change from `#:implements` to `#:implements/inits` in your type definition and call init on the missing value(s) (in this case `stretchable-height`).

If you don't know exactly what those are, you can simply put `(init-rest)` and that should take care of it.

(here's the documentation for [Initialization Variables](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/createclass.html#%28part._clinitvars%29) and [also for `horizontal-panel%`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/horizontal-panel_.html))